# How does this differential simplify

Tags: calculus

How does the following differential from the first line become equal to the second line ?

This is confusing me as I do not know where the 3 has come from.

[image]

Comment: $1 + 1/2 = 3/2$

Comment: What worries me is that it looks like the $e^{-x/2}$ became $e^{-x/3}$.

Comment: Yes that’s true must be a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate $e^{-x/2}$
Then you have $e^{-x/2}(-1 - \frac{1}{2}+\frac x2) = e^{-x/2}(-\frac32+\frac x2) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}(x-3)$

Comment: Thank you I understand now

Comment: You're welcome!